# How to move data from the main class to an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract

Ok so I'm doing a program which collects information about employees and the nsorts them according to how the user wants them sorted. I've successfully created arrays with a loop to store this information but the assignment requires that I use an abstract class with two subclasses to store employee information. So my question is, how do I move the data to these abstract classes to prepare for sorting and stuff.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Assignment55_000848913
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> Names       = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Department  = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Designation = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Float>  Salary      = new ArrayList<Float>();
    String Continue = "y";

    //******************************************************//

    do
{
   System.out.println("Enter Employee Name: ");
   String x = in.next();
   Names.add(x);

   System.out.println("Enter Employee Designation ('temporary or permanent'): ");
   String y = in.next();
   Designation.add(y);

   System.out.println("Enter Employee Department: ");
   String z = in.next();
   Department.add(z);

   System.out.println("Enter Employee Salary: ");
   float i = in.nextFloat();
   Salary.add(i);

   System.out.println("Do you wish to add another employee? ('y'/'n'): ");
   Continue = in.next();
}
while(Continue.equals("y"));


  }

  public abstract class Employee
  {
  ////////
  }

  public class TempEmployee extends Employee
  {
    /////
  }

  public class PermEmployee extends Employee
  {
    /////
  }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing/creating the Lists inside of the abstract class to begin with ( With appropriate accessors ), instead of in the main class. This way you can create a temp employee or perm employee object, and then store the input information directly in the list you've created when you instantiate the object, which will be in-tern stored within the employee class.. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the common information: `name`, `department`, `salary` as fields in the abstract class. Then when you get the input data, create either a new `TempEmployee` or `PermEmployee` depending upon what the input `designation` is. You can add all these employee objects to an `ArrayList<Employee>`, because both `PermEmployee` and `TempEmployee` inherit from `Employee`.

Comment: so, are you saying that I make the arraylist declarations inside of the employee abstract class, and move all the prompts for input inside of there as well? Then I create another list like

Comment: oops sorry, so for example xxx is new TempEmployee();

Comment: Leave the input prompts in main. Then create the new classes depending upon the inputs. You will need to add parameters to the class constructors in order to pass the input data into them,

Comment: what type would i make this array list?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - I  suggested using type Employee in my answer: `ArrayList <Enployee>`. You can add  PermEmployee and TempEmployee objects into this array because both of these classes extend Employee.

Answer (score 0):

Move all the fields to `Employee class` and and add some methods for sorting and other stuff in this class. You can make this these methods abstract bu in that case you have to provide definition in the child classes.

Create two sub-classes like `TempEmployee` and `PermEmloyee`inherit Employee class.

Actually there are many ways this this can be done.